# Locating evenly spaced spikes in time series

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-analysis

I'm trying to detect the presence of (almost) evenly spaced spikes in some temporal data. I only need to detect them so as to flag their presence.

I receive data in blocks ( in the hundreds / few thousands per block) consisting of a noisy graph of non-negative values:

[image: Normal data]

However, sometimes there is an interference and some peaks appear at evenly spaced points:

[image: Bad data]

This figure shows an extreme case, when there are lots of peaks and cover most of the data range. Sometimes those peaks are smaller, and sometimes they cover only a fraction of the range.

To make things harder, due to aliasing the peaks are almost but not exactly evenly spaced ( for example, in the picture the peaks appear at 11, 21, 31, 43, 53, 63, 75, ... ).

I've tried a frequency analysis, but didn't get any significant result (I assume that having such few data points per block and the aliasing of the peaks are both playing against me). There was no discernible pattern in the FFT. There where some peaks in both graphs, but as we don't know in advance the frequency of the peaks, we are faced with the same problem: Locate arbitrary peaks in the graph, only this time in the FFT graph. I got several not so strong peaks in the FFT, sometimes in frequencies not related to that of the peaks.

As of now, I can isolate the peaks by means of the following procedure:

1. Compute a gaussian average around each point.
2. Substract that gaussian average from the value. If the result is negative, make it zero.
3. Keep only the local maxima.

This gives me the following results:

[image: Normal with peaks]
[image: Bad with peaks]

But now I'm stuck. I don't have the slightest idea on how to proceed from here.

Comment: What did happen when you tried using a frequency analysis? That would have been my initial thought and I'm surprised it didn't work.

Comment: @templatetypedef: There was no discernible pattern in the FFT. There where some peaks in both graphs, but as we don't know in advance the frequency of the peaks, we are faced with the same problem: Locate arbitrary peaks in the graph, only this time in the FFT graph.

Comment: I would try computing the autocorrelation function.  A spike train's ACF will have a single very high positive peak at the inter-spike time delta.  It will be easier to look for such a single spike than find the train in the original signal.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez: Within the high-frequency part of the FFT there should be just *one*, very strong peak, so it's not the same problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That was what I expected, but I got several not so strong peaks, sometimes in frequencies not related to that of the peaks. I don't have those results at hand (we discarded them). Will try to reproduce them and upload them.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: For this particular dataset, the FFT approach worked like a charm. Unfortunately I can't recover old datasets that couldn't be analized with a FFT.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the FFT approach did not work. Whatever approach you use you must apply some kind of smoothing/low-pass-filter to eliminate the effects of noise and aliasing. Did you do so?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?